# Close parent window, when a sub window open

Tags: python, qt, authentication, pyqt, pyqt4

The app start with a login form, and when the user and password are correct it start the main window. I can't close the login form (QWidget).

```
def on_pushButton_login_clicked(self):
    username = str(self.ui.lineEdit_usuario.text())
    password = str(self.ui.lineEdit_password.text())
    if login_user(username, password):
        # Hide error if Login fail
        self.ui.label_error.hide()
        window = Main()    # QMainWindow
        try:
            window.exec_()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        #self.close()       # close LoginForm & open QMainWindow
    else:
        self.ui.lineEdit_usuario.setFocus()
        self.ui.lineEdit_usuario.clear()
        self.ui.lineEdit_password.clear()
        # Show error if Login fail
        self.ui.label_error.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If `window` is an instance `QMainWindow`, it won't have an `exec_` method. But if it did, `exec_` implies that the window would be modal and therefore block until the user closed it.

On the other hand, if you used `window.show()` to avoid blocking, the `LoginForm` *would* close itself - but then the `window` would be immediately garbage-collected because you're not keeping a reference to it anywhere.

Assuming `LoginForm` is a `QDialog`, I would suggest you make use of its [accept](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#accept) slot, and then rewrite your startup code to work something like this:

```
class LoginForm(QDialog):
    ...
    def on_pushButton_login_clicked(self):
        username = str(self.ui.lineEdit_usuario.text())
        password = str(self.ui.lineEdit_password.text())
        if login_user(username, password):
            self.accept()
        else:
            ...

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
if LoginForm().exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```